# Start debugging after stop hangs on Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, localhost, iis-express

I start debuging a mvc project. If I stop and start debugging again, visual studio hangs. If I change port and start debugging, it's fine.

The problem: I can't stop and start debugging until I change the port. How can I solve this issue ?

I have tested this in Vs 2013 Ultimate and Vs 2015 Community.
IIS Express version: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear site bindings on `applicationhost.config` and be sure you don't have same port numbers on projects.

For Vs 2015 `applicationhost.config` is at `\ProjectDirectory\.vs\config`.